# Bootstrap dialog in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Angular JS. I started learning Angular JS today. Before I was using jQuery and Bootstrap for front-end. Now I want to show Bootstrap dialog box using AngularJS. I found this, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

But there are so many things difficult for beginners to understand. How can I correct my code to show bootstrap dialog?

This is  my code

```
   <html>
<head>
  <title>Angular</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/angular/bootstrap.css"></link>
  <script src="http://localhost:8888/angular/angular-js.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:8888/angular/angular-js.animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:8888/angular/angular-js.sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:8888/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl">
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
              <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
                      <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $ctrl.selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              Selected: <b>{{ $ctrl.selected.item }}</b>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
          </div>
      </script>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open('lg')">Large modal</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open('sm')">Small modal</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ $ctrl.animationsEnabled }})</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.openComponentModal()">Open a component modal!</button>
      <div ng-show="$ctrl.selected">Selection from a modal: {{ $ctrl.selected }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

  $ctrl.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $ctrl.openComponentModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      component: 'modalComponent',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $ctrl.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $ctrl.animationsEnabled = !$ctrl.animationsEnabled;
  };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

// Please note that the close and dismiss bindings are from $uibModalInstance.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').component('modalComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  bindings: {
    resolve: '<',
    close: '&',
    dismiss: '&'
  },
  controller: function () {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
      $ctrl.items = $ctrl.resolve.items;
      $ctrl.selected = {
        item: $ctrl.items[0]
      };
    };

    $ctrl.ok = function () {
      $ctrl.close({$value: $ctrl.selected.item});
    };

    $ctrl.cancel = function () {
      $ctrl.dismiss({$value: 'cancel'});
    };
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

But my code is not working. There are too many options I do not know in this for example "myModalContent.html" is from where? Would you explain step by step to show Bootstrap dialog box in AngularJS?

I tried this way as well

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Angular</title>
  <script src="angular-js.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-js.animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-js.sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-js.touch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.ui.js"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>

  <div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module("MyApp",["ui.bootstrap.modal"]);

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.showModal = true;
  };
})
</script>
</html>
```

It shows like this:

[image]

It is not working as well. How can I show bootstrap dialog in AngularJS?

Comment: you got some syntax errors there. `ng-controller="myCtrl as as $ctrl"` you got twice the `as` keyword. Furthermore I think the use of the dollar sign for a controller alias is invalid. Use `myCtrl as vm` instead.

Comment: I updated the question. Please have a look. Code is still not working. :(

Comment: have you checked their working sample on plunker?https://plnkr.co/edit/VoLvFSg5d70Zq64w6UI3?p=preview

Comment: I agree with @cleftheris the dollar sign for a controller. Did you update that as well?

Comment: @WaiYanHein are you still having trouble?

Comment: Yeah. I am still struggling with that. I tried in many ways. All not just working for me.

Comment: Ok. We can get it right. Please update the question with the latest code. I'll take a look a bit later.

Comment: that is the most suitable one among I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a ctrl.open function although you ref one in your ng-click.

Maybe you can try this?

```
$ctrl.open = function (size) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
                    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
                    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
                    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                    size: size,
                    resolve: {
                        items: function () {
                            return $ctrl.items;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

`open()` method returns a modal instance. This is what actually creates the modal on your template.

`templateurl` is a path to your template. Here, its looking for `myModalContent.html` in the same path as your controller code. You need to create and design the template and that will get loaded when this modal is called in your view.

`template` can be used here instead of `templateurl` for inline HTML if you do not have enough HTML. "enough" is subjective to your understanding.

`controller` is the name of your controller. You can define it as you like.

`controllerAs` is the alias of your controller. You can define it to be what you like too. `$ctrl` is the alias of your controller by default. If you remove the `controllerAs` option from here, you can still use $ctrl in your template. Although, using this requires you to have `controller` option provided.

`animationsenabled` is a boolean value which can be used to toggle modal animation in your view by toggling the `animation` property. Default is `false`.

`resolve` helps create a `$resolve` object on the opened modal. This helps provide all resolved values from your `items`. Its basically a configuration on the `$routeprovider` service of Angular. To help understand `$resolve` better, you can have a look at [this](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/17/resolve-in-angularjs-routes-explained-as-story/)

Since you are new to Angular, much like me, a great place to start would be to understand [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) in Angular. Its going to be one of your most used feature.

Moreover, you can check out [plunker](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) of the above code, edit it and understand the functioning. I tried it yesterday for the first time too.

Also, add `angular-ui` as a tag to your question so the angular-ui guys can get involved.

Hope this helps in some way.